# zend framework 2 Db Select columns Grouping

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework2

I need a query to my database

This is my database data

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `order_main` (
`om_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'ID',
`om_raren` varchar(20) NOT NULL COMMENT 'serial number',
`om_total` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'money',
`om_freight` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'freight',
`om_amount` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'money + freight',
`om_status` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Order Status：1）Unpaid 2）Paid 3）Cancel 4）Payment     
success,
`om_created` datetime NOT NULL COMMENT 'create time',
PRIMARY KEY (`om_id`)
)
```

My needs,Obtain 4 kinds of data

1)  Not specified 'om_status' , 'om_created' = 2013-01 Items Count

2)  Not specified 'om_status' , 'om_created' = 2013-01' sum('om_total')

3) 'om_status' = 4 , 'om_created = 2013-01' Items Count

3) 'om_status' = 4 , 'om_created' = 2013-01' sum('om_total')

First and second, and I know how to write,like this:

```
$select = $this->tableGateway->getSql()->select();
$select->columns(array(
            'Nub' => new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression('COUNT(*)'),
            'Price' => new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression('sum(`om_total`)'),
        ));
$select->where("DATE_FORMAT(`om_created`, '%Y-%m')  = 2013-01");
$row = $this->tableGateway->selectWith($select)->toArray();
```

But the third and fourth, I don't know how clueless adding that Sql Query, i want 4 kinds of results in the same sql string

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just add another **where()**:

```
...
$select->where("DATE_FORMAT(`om_created`, '%Y-%m')  = 2013-01");
$select->where("om_status = 4");
...
```

Comment: it's not what i want , this's all query data will be 'om_status' = 4, i want 4 kinds of results in  the same sql string

Comment: Hmm I see.. Can you post your SQL query in question?

Comment: Really sorry , because i don't know how to write , so i did not SQL query (= =...)

Comment: I still can not find the answer, now i use another SQL query to perform , To complete the combined results , but still thank u (y)